# Scroll images left or right on button hover

Tags: jquery, scroll, mouseover

I am new in jQuery. I have found this code on stackoverflow this is working fine for scrolling content up and down on mouse over, but I want this content scrolling left and right on mouse over .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Scroll up</title>
<style>
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    width: 178px;
height: 21px;
border:1px solid #000000;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var step = 25;
var scrolling = false;

// Wire up events for the 'scrollUp' link:
$("#scrollUp").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("up");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    scrolling = false;
});


$("#scrollDown").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("down");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    scrolling = false;
});

function scrollContent(direction) {
    var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 1, function() {
        if (scrolling) {
            scrollContent(direction);
        }
    });
}
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <a id="scrollDown" href="#">up</a>
   <a id="scrollUp" href="#">down</a>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">

        <ul>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>            
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/s5mgX/

Answer (score 0):

There is the `marquee` tag, which you can use to scroll text left and right:

Example:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Here is some scrolling text... right to left!</marquee>
```

Comment: i cant use marquee tag it should be in jquery